# there is an error while trying to run command and conquer generals game on my system?

Tags: gaming, hardware-detection, windows-error-reporting

I was given this error while try to run Generals.

I want to know if this system is not good enough to run the game?

- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
- **GPU**: GeForce RTX 3060
- **RAM**: 16GB 3200mhz

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely no, your pc can run the game, just try to click a right-click on the game then click properties then choose compatibility, and press on "**Run this program as an administrator**" then press on "**Run this program in compatibility mode**" and choose "**Window XP pack 3**"

if the game didn't open then the game files are missing try to reinstall the game using the **installer**